Second IPv4 address on NIC in Windows but only for static routes
I have an problem, I don't know what has changed on my Windows 11 PC. Before the configuration with these command works great:

New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.1.2.2 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -SkipAsSource $True

The IP address "10.1.2.1" was only used for connection to static routes (10.1.2.1 is an vpn-gw which has connection to different vpn-nodes). For example we reached the network "192.168.63.0" by adding these by command:

route ADD -p 192.168.63.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.1

Now I need to set -SkipAsSource to $False to get an connection to an network behind the 10.1.2.1 router.
With -SkipAsSource $True, the trace route tell me he uses the primary IP address of  NIC 192.168.178.33, so there will be no reply.
The Problem in -SkipAsSource $True is that all traffic will go through these 10.1.2.2 to 10.1.2.1 (GW). I only want the packets for the vpn-networks, for example 192.168.63.0 go to these.
Does anyone have an idea?
It looks like Windows changed in previous Windows update the logic. For about 2 months the connection was working with -SkipAsSource $False.

Have you tried the "stopping the Host Networking Service"? Also, is Windows 11 enabled for routing? How?
